# draw sine wave on canvas inside Image View in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

How I can draw a sine wave on canvas inside an Image View in android, I need it to be draw in the center of the Image View?

could you help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Canvas.drawPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawPath%28android.graphics.Path,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) to draw any path on your canvas. In this case, the path is your sine, so you have to step through the function values of the sine with a small delta and add each point to the path with [Path.lineTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#lineTo%28float,%20float%29).